# how we can manage cart without login and with login in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

We are developing web and mobile APIs.

How we can manage cart and wishlist without and after login in both platforms in web and mobile app.

Few cases.

1. user can add items to cart and checkout without login.
2. user can checkout after login.

How we can manage on web and mobile application.

for example.
if user added 2 items in cart without login and 3 from mobile  and then he login on mobile first he will see only 2 items because there is only 2 items related to his/her account.

But before mobile checkout if he login on web he will get total 5 items in the cart..

Comment: What do you mean "manage" it? What do you expect to happen? In the example you gave, there's no way for the mobile app to know what was added on the web without the user logging in first. That's just how it is. And it's basically the user's fault, not yours, for not logging in when they could have done.

Comment: just save cart in local storage

Comment: @ADyson  yes are right I just want to confirm I'm right path and not using wrong logic to maintain cart.

Comment: @kas currently I'm using browser local storage to store cart. Should I store DB also?

Comment: No it seems fine. There is no way to link the carts unless the user logs in on the web at some point. At that point you can store them centrally so the items are available on both web and mobile. But if they don't do that, you can't

Comment: Once user gets login I'am storing cart both side (browser and( DB with user id))

Comment: That's as much as you can do, then. Your approach is fine